# Pass dialog variables to function in Simulink mask initialization

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am creating self modifying Simulink blocks using the Initialization pane of the Mask Editor. Rather than work directly in the text editor of the Initialization pane, I would like to call something like `init_blk(gcb)` and write my code in `init_blk.m` so I can debug using break points. This approach works okay, but I find myself explicitly passing an ever growing list of variables.  Rather than have a function of the form `init_blk(gcb,param1,param2,param3, ...)` I want something along the lines of `init_blk(gcb,DialogParamters)`.  I have been able to access DialogParamters inside `init_blk()` using `get_param` but this doesn't seem to preserve datatypes.  Everything is a string.

So the gist of my question is this.  What do I need to enter into the Initialization commands pane in order to pass whatever workspace is active for the initialization commands to a function?  Or is there a better way of handling this altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use

```
get_param(gcb,'MaskWSVariables')
```

Comment: This gets me most of the way there, and also led me to the discovery of `get_param(gcb,'MaskNames')` and `get_param(gcb,'MaskValues')`.  Some behavior I still don't quite understand is the handling of strings vs doubles.  `get_param(gcb,'MaskWSVariables')` returns a struct where the `Value` member is empty for strings and a double for doubles.  On the other hand `get_param(gcb,'MaskValues')` returns all values as strings.  If I use `class()` inside the Initialization pane text block directly the parameters are correctly identified as strings or doubles.